# Why does list insertion fail when sufficient size is provided on construction?

Tags: c#, list

If we have the following variable declaration:

```
List<int> list = new List(5);
```

Why does this:

```
list.insert(2, 3);
```

fail with the following error:

```
Index must be within the bounds of the List.
```

What's the point of providing the initial size?

Comment: You can't insert at position 2, if positions 0 and 1 are not yet filled

Comment: As correctly pointed out, the capacity is not the same as size. Write the Count to the console before calling Insert, the list has less then 3 items, so inserting new value to the 3rd position fails.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All the initial size does is [provide a hint to the implementation to have at least a given capacity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dw8e0z9z.aspx). It does not create a list filled with `N` default entries; emphasis mine:

> Initializes a new instance of the `List<T>` class **that is empty** and has the specified initial capacity.

If you continue through the MSDN entry to the Remarks section, you'll find why this constructor overload is provided (again, emphasis mine):

> The capacity of a `List<T>` is the number of elements that the `List<T>` can hold. As elements are added to a `List<T>`, the capacity is automatically increased as required by reallocating the internal array.
>
> If the size of the collection can be estimated, specifying the initial capacity **eliminates the need to perform a number of resizing operations** while adding elements to the `List<T>`.

In short `List<T>.Count` is not the same as `List<T>.Capacity` ("If Count exceeds Capacity while adding elements, the capacity is increased...").

You receive the exception because the list only *logically* contains the items you add, changing the capacity does not change the number of items *logically* stored. If you were to set `List<T>.Capacity` to less than `List<T>.Count` we can test this behavior going the other direction:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: capacity was less than
 the current size.
Parameter name: value
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.set_Capacity(Int32 value)
```

To perhaps create the behavior you're looking for:

```
public static List<T> CreateDefaultList<T>(int entries)
{
    return new List<T>(new T[entries]);
}
```

Comment: Then what does it use that hint for if not to create an initial backing store?

Comment: The `List<T>` does not *have* to use an array for a backing store, it could use a `LinkedList<T>` or some other implementation. All you're doing is telling it to *expect* `N` entries in the hopes that the performance impact of expanding the list to hold that many entries will be negligible.

Comment: It simply means that it can receive 5 items before the List object needs to grow. It's a performance optimization.

Comment: @Erix The initial capacity you provide helps the CLR know how much memory you intend to use for the list. It in no way limits you to that initial capacity. In fact it will use the initial capactity as a hint on how many new memory locations to set aside when a resize is necessary.

Comment: Nitpick: List is documented as using an array backing store.  From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx, "The List(Of T) class is the generic equivalent of the ArrayList class. It implements the IList(Of T) generic interface using an array whose size is dynamically increased as required."

Comment: @ChrisShain: I agree (and I don't think my answer contradicts that), however, that is merely an implementation detail ("Remarks"). They could special case situations where capacity is less than some N to use private fields, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Internally a [List(T)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) is implemented using an array in the background. When you initialize the list that way you are just setting the size of the underlying array which resizes as the list grows. Thus, you are initializing the initial capacity. It doesn't mean that your list has that many elements.

You add elements to the list by first initializing it and then add elements to it with `.Add(item)`.

Answer (score 0):

Because insert assumes that the list actually has that many items already inserted- capacity is not the same thing as size.  Initializing the list with a given capacity just sets the size of the internal array- it is an optimization to prevent array resizes when you know the number of items that you are going to be inserting.

Answer (score 0):

The List(int) constructor specifies initial capacity of the list.  It does not specify the number of initial elements.  Upon construction a list is empty so, any insertion can only be done at index 0.

Answer (score 0):

The size in the constructor tells it how much to allocate for the background array - it is still, however, empty (just: empty with a certain amount of initial space).

You can ony insert into the used part of the list, or at the end.

Answer (score 0):

The initial size is used to indicate the size of the internal array, initially.

When you insert items into a List, it stores them in an array. When the array is full, it creates a new array of double the size, and copies all of the items. If you have an idea that you are going to be putting in 5000 items, you would want to specify that hint so it doesn't end up doing a lot of array resizing / copying.

The initial size does *not* indicate that there are any items in the list though.

Answer (score 0):

That is because the integer you specify in the constructor is the amount that the List can hold. When items are added, the list is automatically increased. The resizing is avoided when you specify an initial capacity that matches the number of items that you want to add.

However, you still have to use the Add method to add new items.

See the [remarks section in the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dw8e0z9z.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
listItem.Addrange(number);
```